# Lambda Check if method is POST

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am defining a USER view. It does something like this->
If method is GET -> Lambda interacts with RDS on the backend and return all the USER views.

```
GET /list-views/users/user_id/list_object_types/list_object_type_id
```

If method is Create -> A new user will be created and added into RDS.

```
POST /list-views/create
```

If method is delete -> A user will be deleted.

```
PATCH /list-views/id
```

I am able to do this by creating function in lambda like this->

```
def fetch_thing(method):
    if method == "POST":
        API_ENDPOINT = ""
        dataa={"type" : "abc", "price" : 123.11}

        xz = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, json = dataa)
        re=xz.json()


    elif method == "GET":
        r11 = requests.get(url="")
        re = r11.json()

    return re
```

But when I try to integrate this with Lambda, It gives the error as "Integration has to be defined"
I believe it is because my main lambda_handler-> *Note this is what I have been trying to make it run as until this is mentioned over here, it won't let me integrate lambda with API.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

if event['queryStringParameters']['paramName'] == "POST":
    return "hi"
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful, The goal is to whenever a new user creates a view, lambda updates the RDS table, I am doing this by checking the method request and then submitting this via API endpoints to the Front End developers

Comment: Create a ANY method in API and integrate it with a Lambda proxy integration. You can access the value used by your client using 'httpMethod' under 'requestContext' https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpMethod attribute of the event parameter

```
if (event.httpMethod === 'POST') {
    //...
}
```